# setHeader filename not working on IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, header, response, itext

I'm saving a pdf file with the following part of the code:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", 
        "inline; filename="+pd.getName()+"_"+version+".pdf") ; 
    response.setContentLength(baosPDF.size()); 
    java.io.OutputStream os;
    os = response.getOutputStream();
    baosPDF.writeTo(os);
```

When I right click on save the file in my page, in Chrome and Firefox it is named correctly by default:

```
"NameOfPd_VersionNumber.pdf"
```

But only in Internet Explorer 8 is named:

```
"printPDFAction.pdf"
```

where printPDFAction is the name of the action which creates the pdf.

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing `inline` with `attachment`

Comment: also, for IE add these headers: `Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate` and `Pragma: public`

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek it works, answer so I can accept and close the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="xxx.pdf"
```

also for IE, use these headers (IE sometimes has problems opening files which it saved a moment ago):

```
Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: public
```